Theorem 7.39 in Apostol's MATHEMATICAL ANALYSIS, 2nd ed: How to extract $g$ from $G$?
Here is Theorem 7.39, in Chapter 7, in the book Mathematical Analysis - A Modern Approach to Advanced Calculus by Tom M. Apostol, 2nd edition:

If $f$ is continuous on the rectangle $[a, b] \times [c, d]$, and if $g \in R$ on $[a, b]$, then the function $F$ defined by the equation
$$
F(y) = \int_a^b f(x, y) g(x) dx
$$
is continuous on $[c, d]$. That is, if $y_0 \in [c, d]$, we have
$$
\lim_{y \to y_0} \int_a^b f(x, y) g(x) dx = \int_a^b f \left(x, y_0 \right) g(x) dx. 
$$

And, here is Apostol's proof:

If $G(x) = \int_a^x g(t) dt$, Theorem 7.26 shows that $F(y) = \int_a^b f(x, y) d G(x)$. Now apply Theorem 7.38.

Here is Theorem 7.26 in ApostoL:

Assume $f \in R(\alpha)$ and $g \in R(\alpha)$ on $[a, b]$, where $\alpha \nearrow$ on $[a, b]$. Define
$$
F(x) = \int_a^x f(t) d\alpha(t) \qquad \mbox{ and } \qquad G(x) = \int_a^x g(t) d\alpha(t) \qquad \mbox{ if } x \in [a, b].
$$
Then $f \in R(G)$, $g \in R(F)$, and $f \cdot g \in R(\alpha)$ on $[a, b]$, and we have
$$
\int_a^b f(x) g(x) d\alpha(x) = \int_a^b f(x) dG(x) = \int_a^b g(x) dF(x). 
$$

And, here is Theorem 7.38:

Let $f$ be continuous at each point $(x, y)$ of a rectangle
$$
Q = \big\{ (x, y) \colon a\leq x \leq b, c \leq y \leq d \big\}. 
$$
Assume that $\alpha$ is of bounded variation on $[a, b]$ and let $F$ be the function defined on $[c, d]$ by the equation
$$
F(y) = \int_a^b f(x, y) d\alpha(x). 
$$
Then $F$ is continuous on $[c, d]$. In other words, if $y_0 \in [c, d]$, we have
$$
\lim_{y \to y_0} \int_a^b f(x, y) d\alpha(x) = \int_a^b \lim_{y \to y_0}  f(x, y) d\alpha(x) = \int_a^b f \left(x, y_0 \right) d\alpha(x).
$$

Finally, here is Theorem 7.32 in Apostol:

Let $\alpha$ be of bounded variation on $[a, b]$ and assume that $f \in R(\alpha)$ on $[a, b]$. Define $F$ by the equation
$$
F(x) = \int_a^b f d\alpha, \qquad \mbox{ if } x\in [a, b].
$$
Then we have:


i) $F$ is of bounded variation on $[a, b]$.


ii) Every point of continuity of $\alpha$ is also a point of continuity of $F$.


iii) If $\alpha \nearrow$ on $[a, b]$, the derivative $F^\prime(x)$ exists at each point $x$ in $(a, b)$ where $\alpha^\prime(x)$ exists and where $f$ is continuous. For such $x$, we have
$$
F^\prime(x) = f(x) \alpha^\prime(x). 
$$

Now of course the function $G$ in Apostol's proof is continuous and of bounded variation on $[a, b]$. However, how to apply Theorem 7.26 to the function $f(x, y)$? After all, Theorem 7.26 has been stated only for functions $f$ of only a single variable.

You can just assume $y$ to be constant and apply theorem 7.26 so that for each value $y\in[c, d] $ the desired result holds.
